# Netty and Maximum Concurrent connection size

Tags: java, netty

I am developing a Netty based server where at the number of concurrent connections should be around 100000. However when I set that number to 100 I do not run out of memory but when I increase the number to 10000 I got outmoemory buffer exception. Knowing that Netty can handle even more than what I amexpecting I would like to know how to set the serverbootstrap to cater for such a great number.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With how much memory are you running this program? Since it is `OutOfMemoryException` getting thrown, it looks like you can just change the `-Xmx` setting to something like `-Xmx2048m` and see if it works. This may not have anything to do with netty per se.

If you are convinced that there is a leak, then use tools like [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) (which is free by the way!) to analyze if any netty objects are on the heap even after requests/gc's are done.

In linux, you generally get `too many open files` exception when running so many concurrent connections, there is a ton of documentation out there on how to resolve it.